# In Visual studio 2005 if your cursor is in middle of the method how to go to the start place where method definition started?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

In Visual studio 2005 if your cursor is in middle of the method how to go to the start place where method definition is started ?

Comment: Press control and click on the method

Comment: keep pressing the up arrow key until you get there :)